# Hibernate 2LC with infinispan holds stale entities after transaction rollback

Tags: hibernate, wildfly, infinispan

I run a JEE application on a WildFly 23.0.2 server (Hibernate 5.3.20, Infinispan 11.0.9). I have default settings for the second level cache, this includes the region settings in the wildfly config (standalone-full.xml) as well as the configuration for Hibernate (persistence.xml):

```
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />

<cache-container name="hibernate" modules="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache">
  <local-cache name="entity">
    <heap-memory size="10000"/>
    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
  </local-cache>
  <local-cache name="local-query">
    <heap-memory size="10000"/>
    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
  </local-cache>
  <local-cache name="timestamps"/>
  <local-cache name="pending-puts">
    <expiration max-idle="60000"/>
  </local-cache>
</cache-container>
```

I have an entity that uses optimistic lock detection ('version' property) and cache strategy 'transactional':

```
<cache usage="transactional" />
<version generated="never" name="version" type="long" />
```

I have a larget set (> 2000) of those entities which are modified concurrently by two transactions. As expected, one of the transactions runs into an OptmisticLockException when the session is flushed. The other transaction finishes without errors or exceptions. While the database now holds the updated state of the entities, the second level cache still holds the old state. Further reads will now return the old state from 2LC and can no longer be updated, because it has an old version.

I recently upgraded from WildFly 10 where this problem did not occur.

Comment: Hi, whats the Infinispan version?

Comment: I've updated the versions in the question: Hibernate 5.3.20, Infinispan 11.0.9

Comment: "when the session is flushed". session, do you mean the Hibernate Session? Are you doing session.flush or are you letting the WF take care of that? I am asking because I will try to work in a reproducer for this issue

Comment: Can you post the link to the issue here so people can track this problem?

Comment: The stack trace tells me that the OptimisticLockException occurs during session flush. Transaction management should be handled by JTA (or maybe there is a misconfiguration, but i think not so, datasource is configured as 'jta-data-source')

Comment: We have identified a problem in the underlying hibernate infinispan integration and opened a ticket for this issue: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-13596